# Yesod CSS lucius

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yesod

I have made a table in my hamlet file:

```
<table>
$forall ivlist <- y
    <tr>
      $forall iv <- ivlist
        <td>^{fvInput iv}
```

and its respective css in lucius file:

```css
td {
    width:1em;
    height:1em;
}
```

The CSS was also generated as expected,but the output was different. When I change the `height` and `width` to some higher value the change was visible, but when I change it to sum lower value it no longer decreases.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ReZn.png) is the image of the generated table

[image: Image-table]

I couldn't change the column `width`.I wanted to make it square. But i don't know what should be done. I am using a static **bootstrap.css** file and also each cell is a `input`. I think the problem should be due to some default values in bootstrap. but I couldn't find what should be changed. I have tried few changes like changing `width` and modifying the **bootstrap.css** file, but I didn't get the required results.

```css
input[type="range"] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

In short how do I modify the cell `width`?
What should I be modifying to see the changes in the `width` of the `table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It was simple. The change was to be made to the `input` tag. So  I added the following to my lucius file

```
input {
    width:3em;
}
```

which was allowing me to control the width.